# How unique are the last 4 digits of a credit card?

Tags: credit-card

In our application we use the card type and last 4 digits provided by a merchant terminal as a unique identifier for customers. For example `VISA-1234`.

Since the card number is not actually random (based on the [lunh algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)) do we really get 10,000 combinations for the last 4 digits or is it a smaller subset? If so, is it possible to calculate or even estimate this number?

Comment: The last digit of a credit card number is a checksum, so there are only 1,000 combinations of the last 4 digits for a credit card issuer.  If you really want 10,000 numbers, you would need to save the last 5 digits.

Comment: ...and you can't store the last 5 digits as that is not PCI-DSS compliant. PCI states you can store first six, last four (at most) in plaintext.

Comment: @PaulG - that won't be a problem because the 4 digits are provided from the device, we never handle any more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are potentially 10,000 combinations of the last four digits. The fact that the last digit is a Luhn check digit does not alter this fact.

As an example, these 10 card numbers have valid luhn digits from 0 through 9. This list has been generated by modifying the 7th digit of the card number in each:

424242**0**242424240
424242**9**242424241
424242**4**242424242
424242**8**242424243
424242**3**242424244
424242**7**242424245
424242**2**242424246
424242**6**242424247
424242**1**242424248
424242**5**242424249

As an aside, PCI-DSS only allows plain text storage of (at most) the first six and last four digits.